# Can't connect to my EC2 instance through the public IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to AWS so please help me, I installed ATX (Professional Tax Software for Accountants) on it , and I cant access it through the public IP, I tried all the suggestions in the forums, I enabled http port on security group, It is reachable when I ping it.

Comment: Is your application running on port 80?

Answer (score 3):

You can proceed with the following:

1. Check ssh connection on your server
2. While logged inside the machine, try performing a "curl http://localhost:port" where port is the port number where your ATX app is running, if you cannot get a response, please check the installation itself, if you can, proceed with 3:
3. Check the security group that your ec2 instance belongs to, does it has a rule to allow inbound traffic on the port that the ATX is using to run? Also check that the mentioned inbound rule states your public ip as source, or the CIDR block your ip belongs to. If it still doesn't work check 4.
4. Check that your ec2 instance has access to the internet, if not, add an internet gateway to the vpc your instance belongs to.

This list should cover 99% of what could be the problem.